# Script creating file with >& fails w/ file not found on next line

Tags: bash

I was running a bash script and encountered an error. I don't understand why it happened.

```
#!/bin/bash
./autogen.sh >& $LIB-autogen
mv $LIB-autogen $DATA_DIR/$LIB/
```

It reported an error message:

```
mv: cannot stat `ex-autogen': No such file or directory
```

autogen.sh is a script to generate configure file and that script works well.

Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

Comment: First -- which version of bash are you running? Second -- did you start the script with `sh scriptname`, `./scriptname`, or some other way?

Comment: I am using version 4.1.2. I start the script with ./scriptname. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes

```
mv "$LIB-autogen" "$DATA_DIR/$LIB"
```

From Charles Duffy:

> Without knowing the exact values of DATA_DIR, LIB, and IFS (an
>   internal shell setting), one can't tell whether operating without the
>   double-quotes is safe or not. Operating with the double quotes, by
>   contrast, is always safe, inasmuch as string-splitting and glob
>   expansion cannot occur. This answer, then, is generally sound advice,
>   inasmuch as it forecloses possible problems which might otherwise
>   occur.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please let me know why double quotes is necessary for this case?

Comment: @ZackLi, without knowing the exact values of `DATA_DIR`, `LIB`, and `IFS` (an internal shell setting), one can't tell whether operating without the double-quotes is safe or not. Operating _with_ the double quotes, by contrast, is always safe, inasmuch as string-splitting and glob expansion cannot occur. This answer, then, is generally sound advice, inasmuch as it forecloses possible problems which might otherwise occur.

Answer (score 1):

`>&` is an alternative way to write `&>`, itself a fairly new redirection operator -- one could conceive of running a version of bash that doesn't have it.

```
./autogen.sh >"$LIB-autogen" 2>&1
```

...would be the more compatible way to send both stdout and stderr of `autogen.sh` to the appropriately named file.