# How to copy with files with spaces with cp command

Tags: shell, spaces, cp

I am copying files with spaces with the help of small script `for f in "$file"; do echo "$f"; cp $f ~/Documents/; done`. `echo` command works well and returns full name of files

```
DailyTransactionLedger.xls
12722 FinRep.xlsx
RP - Jul 2022.pdf
```

But `copy` command gives mess.

```
cp: cannot stat '12722': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'FinRep.xlsx': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'RP': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '-': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'Jul': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '2022.pdf': No such file or directory
```

Do somebody has any insights?

Comment: You know you should quote variables everywhere, but why not `cp`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script creating file with >& fails w/ file not found on next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199219/script-creating-file-with-fails-w-file-not-found-on-next-line)

Comment: As you see the variable in double quotes